# Transferring values to SQL query with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I need transfer the ID value to my like query, i am trying search the value that my getInfo include in his id. If i submitin with an id equipment i get the requested results , with GET or POST is not working . How can i get the id of my getInfo to my LIKE query ?

```
                    echo "<tr style='width:150px'>";
                        echo "
                        <td>$row[id]</td>
                        <td>$row[name]</td>
                        <td>$row[username]</td>
                        <td>$row[asset_tag]</td>
                        <td><form action=\"\"><input class=\"btn\" id=$row[id] type=\"submit\" value=\"getInfo\" name=\"getInfo\" action=\"searchform.php\" method=\"GET\"></td>

                        ";
                    echo "</tr>";
}


echo "</table>";

}{

if( isset($_GET['getInfo'])){
                        $query = "SELECT 
                        equipments.id,
                        equipments.name,
                        auth_user.username,
                        equipments.asset_tag,
                        equiepments_history.comment
                        FROM equipments
                        LEFT JOIN equiepments_history
                        ON equipments.id=equiepments_history.equipment_id
                        LEFT JOIN auth_user
                        ON equipments.holder_employee_id=auth_user.id
                        WHERE equiepments_history.equipment_id 
                        LIKE '%".$_GET['id']."%'
                        AND name <> '' ;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it from a form to a simple link.

```
<td>$row[id]</td>
<td>$row[name]</td>
<td>$row[username]</td>
<td>$row[asset_tag]</td>
<td><a href=\"searchform.php?getInfo=1&id=$row[id]\">Get Info</a></td>
```

Then you can grab the variables and use them in your query.
Never use an unsanitised variable in your query though.

```
if( isset($_GET['getInfo'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];

...
...

//sql 
LIKE '%". $id ."%'
//etc
```

You really should be looking into prepared statements and PDO though as they are much safer or at the very least http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php